# How to send a brokermessage that is a list of other types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I'm trying to send a broker message to a service bus and I want the message to be a list of multiple types. I've tried using interfaces as well as objects and it works fine until I add more than one type to the list. I'm read several posts and online articles about doing something similar and they all seem to be specific to doing manual xml seralization or using WCF. In this case the seralization is happening automatically.

My code is like so:

```
   Queue<Object> x = new Queue<Object>();
                    x.Enqueue(new VRequest());
                    x.Enqueue(new PRequest());
                    ServiceBus.TrackerClient.SendAsync(new BrokeredMessage(x) { ContentType = "BulkRequest" });
```

Then my broker message handler (where a seralization error occurs):

```
  var bulk = message.GetBody<Queue<Object>>();
```

**Any ideas on how I can send a single broker message with multiple types?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone interested you can use a binary formatter and memory stream to accomplish this. It's super flexible since you are working binary data... You can even use interfaces, etc. You will need to convert to a byte array once you have the memory stream so you can send it over the network. Then you are able to deserialize it on the other end. Also make sure you mark your objects are serializable.

```
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        Queue<IYodas> q = new Queue<IYodas>();
        q.Enqueue(new Yoda());
        q.Enqueue(new Yoda2());

        formatter.Serialize(stream, q);
        Byte[] package = stream.ToArray();

       // Send broker message using package as the object to send
       ....

        // Then on the other end (you will need a byte array to object function)
        Queue<IYodas> result = (Queue<IYodas>)ByteArrayToObject(package);
```

Comment: You can find a bytearraytobject method here: http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/C-Sharp/C-Code-Snippet-Byte-array-to-object.html